# How to measure the length of a given curve precisely?

Tags: calculus

Draw the function

$$
f(x)=2x^4+3x^3-2x+8
$$ 
into a cartesian plane.

> How to measure the exact length of that curve from $x=2.2$ to $x=33.64$ ? Is it true that we can measure the exact length of that curve just using the differential/calculus function or some sort?

Comment: $\text{infinitesimal increment of arc length} = \sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}$. (See my answer below for the more complete explanation.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: How to measure Thor's whip. This answers it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A length of a curve $y=f(x)$ from point $a$ to point $b$, so called Arc Lenght, is given by
$$L = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2}dt$$

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ArcLength.aspx

The formula is of an exact length of course. However, this is elliptical integral (hyperelliptical in your case) which is often have to be approximated numerically, like in your case, so the end of story the length won't really be exact.

The approximation of your specific problem obtained using Mathematica gives
$$\int_{2.2}^{33.64} \sqrt{1+\left(8 x^3+9 x^2-2\right)^2}\, dx = 
2.67533\times 10^6$$

Comment: Since this is the integral of the square root of a 6th degree polynomial, doing this any way but numerically seems hopeless.

Comment: that is very true

Comment: Michael, does this formula give an exact length of any curve/arc ?

Comment: @lina, yes, it does.

Comment: read the edit$$

Comment: This is *not* an elliptic integral. To be an elliptic integral, the expression under the square root has to be of degree 3 or 4.

Comment: The length is about 2.6 million ? That's a very long line !

Comment: @martycohen I mean that it has a form of elliptic integral in general, but yes for this specific $f$ it become not elliptic. Does it have another generic name?

Comment: @linalawrence $33^4=1,185,921$ ... so yes...

Comment: Hyperelliptic or Abelian functions. Maybe.

Answer (score 4):

$$
ds = \text{infinitesimal increment of arc length} = \sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}.
$$
That is an application of the Pythagorean theorem.

Therefore
$$
\text{arc length} = \int_{x=2.2}^{x=33.64} \sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}.
$$

Then do a bit of algebra:
\begin{align}
& dy = f'(x)\,dx, \text{ so } (dy)^2 = f'(x)^2(dx)^2, \text{ and consequently } \\[10pt]
& \sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2} = \sqrt{(dx)^2+f'(x)^2(dx)^2} = \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} \sqrt{(dx)^2} = \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} \  dx.
\end{align}

Comment: So, what is the exact length of that curve from x=2.2 to 33.64 ?

Comment: @linalawrence : You'd have to actually evaluate the integral to get that.  It's rather messy and might have to be done numerically rather than in closed form. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Since Ms Lawrence is sceptical, in SIA we have Taylor's formula:
$$f(x + \varepsilon) = f(x) + \varepsilon f'(x)$$
If s gives the curve length:
$$s(x + \varepsilon) - s(x) = \varepsilon s'(x)$$
Where the RHS is a microstraight portion of the curve. Therefore:
$$\varepsilon s'(x) = \sqrt{\varepsilon^2 + (\varepsilon f'(x))^2 }$$
From Pythagoras, which simplifies to:
$$s'(x) = \sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2 }$$
$$s(x) = \int\sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2 }$$
In non-SIA a dx is added to the RHS by convention, but to numerically evaluate the length you would use the above equation, unless you use very small secants of course.

Comment: o I see, you mean we must evaluate the length of this curve part by part, but actually we approximate the exact length ?

Comment: @lina lawrence Yes, I think. I would do it with multiple small secants. Is this something you actually *need* to do?

Comment: No,I just had a little doubt about the precision : )

Comment: But I'm now convinced that this formula is indeed give an exact length of that curve by infinitely approximating the exact length : )

Answer (score 1):

Ever since Newton introduced " fluxions" there is only one answer.

If the derivative $ 8 x^3 + 9 x^2 - 2 $  is labelled $ y^{'}$, then the length 
$$ = \int_{2.2 }^ {33.64}  \sqrt{1+  y^{'2}} dx $$

To get exactness the curve must be accurately drawn, measuring contact sides raised out of the sketched plane using some hardenable plastic material of proper rigidity and flexibility, a flexible tape used ( like one used for tailoring , steel tape wont flex around corners)... but before all that, may be better to measure on available circular arcs to verify theory .

Answer (score 1):

The exact length of that curve must be greater than $f(33.64)-f(2.2)=2675326.03$. Because we can picture that curve **roughly** as a hypotenuse of a right triangle and the vertical line from $y=f(2.2)$ to $y=f(33.64)$ as the vertical side of that right triangle. So the the exact length of that curve from $x=2.2$ to $33.64$ **must be** greater than $2675326.03$.(A MUST)